# How to navigate between pages using Electron and React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm kinda new to Electron and I'm using the [React template](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) (since I do know that framework), I'm trying to navigate between 2 components, Homepage and Login page, usually I've been used to do something like this:

```js
<Router>
 <Switch>
   <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
   <Route path="/Login" exact component={Login} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

But in electron it doesn't render any component, I do only get the background, even if I kill or reload the app.

[image]

How can I solve? are there any files that I can add to hep you?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try two things:

**1.**
Just try switching the order like this:

```
<Route path="/Login" exact component={Login} />
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
```

I don't know why, but it often gives me the problem of not rendering anything if the order of all  is not in a certain way. That is something I need to research.

**2.**

Try rendering component by using `render()` which is explained here:
[1]: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

So you will do it like this:

```
      <Route
      path="/" component={Home} render={() => (
        <Home />
      )}
      />
```

You can also try to exclude `component={Home}`.